# rigid type variable trouble/suspect Impredicativity

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, gadt

Following on from [this q about GADTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919548/gadts-for-a-dsl-swings-and-roundabouts), I'm trying to build an EDSL (for the example in the paper) but without GADTs. I have got something working that avoids doubling-up the datatypes for the AST; but instead it seems to be doubling-up the code. So I tried trimming down the code, which is where I've run into trouble ...

Instead of a GADT like so

```
data Term a where
  Lit ::      Int -> Term Int
  Inc :: Term Int -> Term Int
  IsZ :: Term Int -> Term Bool
  -- etc
```

declare each constructor as a separate datatype

```
data Lit   = Lit Int  deriving (Show, Read)
data Inc a = Inc a    deriving (Show, Read)
data IsZ a = IsZ a    deriving (Show, Read)
-- etc
```

Then the EDSL user can enter and `show` terms

```
aTerm = IsZ (Inc (Lit 5))

illtypedTerm = Inc (IsZ (Lit 5))    -- accepted OK and can show
                                    -- but can't eval [good!]
```

Then to catch that they're all `Term`s and need to be well-typed

```
data Term a = ToTerm { fromTerm :: a} deriving (Show, Eq)

class IsTerm a c  | a -> c 
instance IsTerm Lit (Term Int) 
-- etc
```

The FunDep captures the return type from the original GADT. Then `eval` can use that `Term` type

```
class Eval a   
  where eval :: (IsTerm a c) => a -> c 
                             -- hmm this makes 'c' a rigid tyvar
instance Eval Lit  where    
         eval (Lit i) = -- undefined     -- accepted OK, infers :: Term Int
                        ToTerm i         -- rejected
```

The equation `eval (Lit i) = undefined` (commented out) compiles OK, and GHC infers `eval (Lit 5) :: Term Int`. But if I put `= ToTerm i`:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `c' with actual type `Term Int'
  `c' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      eval :: forall c. IsTerm Lit c => Lit -> c
* Relevant bindings include
    eval :: Lit -> c
```

If GHC can infer (via the FunDep) that `c` must be `Term Int` for `= undefined`, why can't it for `= ToTerm i`? Is the specialised type sig it's inferred `eval :: forall c. IsTerm Lit c => Lit -> c` Impredicative? But `c` is the return type, so it's not RankN(?)

What avoids this error? I do have working

- `class (IsTerm a c) => Eval a c  | a -> c  where ...` this just duplicates all the instance heads from `IsTerm`, so the superclass constraint is only acting as belt and braces. (That's the doubling-up I was trying to avoid.)
- `type family ToTerm a ...; class Eval a  where eval :: a -> ToTerm a`. But again the instances for `Eval` double-up all the instances for `ToTerm`, and furthermore need large contexts with many `~` constraints between `ToTerm` calls.

I could just throw away class `IsTerm`, and put all the Term-inference on class `Eval`. But I was trying to closely mirror the GADT style such that I might have many application 'clients' sharing the same definition for Term.

**Addit:** [March 14]

The 2011 paper [System F with Type Equality Coercions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/tldi22-sulzmann-with-appendix.pdf?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fum%2Fpeople%2Fsimonpj%2Fpapers%2Fext-f%2Ftldi22-sulzmann-with-appendix.pdf), Section 2.3, has this example (in discussing Functional Dependencies)

```
class F a b | a -> b
instance F Int Bool

class D a where { op :: F a b => a -> b }
instance D Int where { op _ = True }
```

> Using FC, this problem [of typing the definition of `op` in the instance `D Int`] is easily solved: the coercion in the dictionary for `F` enables the result of `op` to be cast to type `b` as required.

- This example seems to be the same as the q, with class `F`, with FunDep, being `IsTerm` and class `D` being `Eval`.
- This example doesn't compile: gives the same rejection as `IsTerm/Eval`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077731/printing-church-booleans q & answer seems to apply: the instance here returning `ToTerm i` is not allowing just any type for `c`. OTOH it is allowing any type that meets the `IsTerm a c =>` constraint on method `eval`. So(?) GHC is ignoring the constraint? Or isn't clever enough to see the constraint has a FunDep that improves `c` to exactly the type of `ToTerm i`.

Answer (score 1):

> If GHC can infer (via the FunDep) that c must be Term Int for = undefined

It can't. If you try `undefined :: Term Int`, you'll get the same rigid type variable error. If you use a typed hole `= _undefined` you'll see it's inferring `undefined :: c`. I don't know why, but the functional dependency only seems to be used when *applying* `eval` to `Lit`, not when defining it.

What about this?

```
class IsTerm a where
  type TermType a :: *
instance IsTerm Lit where
  type TermType Lit = Int
instance IsTerm a => IsTerm (Inc a) where
  type TermType (Inc a) = TermType a

class IsTerm a => Eval a   
  where eval :: a -> Term (TermType a) 

instance Eval Lit  where    
         eval (Lit i) = ToTerm i

-- needs UndecidableInstances
instance (Eval a, Num (TermType a)) => Eval (Inc a)  where    
         eval (Inc i) = ToTerm (fromTerm (eval i) + 1)
```

Comment: "It can't  ... I don't know why". Other qs on `rigid type variable`s suggest I need a RHS of type no less general than bare `c`. So is the `IsTerm` constraint just ignored? Your suggestion of associated TF `TermType` seems even more verbose than my top-level TF `ToTerm`; why make it associated? What I mean by "large contexts" is for `data If b a1 a2 = ...` whose `Eval` instance requires `IsTerm b (Term Bool)` and the Term type of `a1, a2` to be the same, and that's the type of the result. The instance for a two-param `Eval` is more succinct, even with the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `IsTerm` constraint is on method `eval`, not a superclass constraint on `Eval` -- it couldn't be there because the return type `c` of `eval` is not a parameter to the class.

Then it's misleading to consider `instance Eval Lit` in isolation. Consider the instance for `Inc`, and its instance for `IsTerm`:

```
instance ( {-# tba #-} ) => Eval (Inc a)  where
  eval (Inc i) = ToTerm $ 1 + fromTerm (eval i)

instance (IsTerm a (Term int)) => IsTerm (Inc a) (Term Int)
```

What should that `tba` constraint include?

- The method body has a recursive call to `eval`, so it needs `Eval a` for that.
- The method body's `1 + ... eval ...` needs `eval` to return an `Int`, but the `Eval` constraint doesn't provide that (because it doesn't mention the return type).
- Could a constraint `IsTerm a (Term Int)` provide it? No: `IsTerm` is (at best) implied by `Eval`, not the other way round.

So the only way this could hang together without a lot of duplication is if:

- The compiler saw the recursive call to `eval`; magically added an `IsTerm a c1` constraint for it; found the applicable instance of `IsTerm` for `a`; and then figured out that `IsTerm` instance yielded `c1 ~ Term Int`.
- But if all it has is bare `a`, there's no way to know which instance. So leave the constraint as Wanted pending getting `eval` applied to `(Inc x)` for some term `x`?

Contrast that in the GADT definition for `Inc`, its argument needs to be `Term Int`. This is the straitjacket that prevents an EDSL user entering an ill-typed term:

```
  Inc :: Term Int -> Term Int
```

As to the specific rejection message for the `instance Eval Lit`, I think Hugs' wording makes it clearer:

```
- Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : eval
*** Expected type : (Eval Lit, IsTerm Lit a) => Lit -> a
*** Inferred type : (Eval Lit, IsTerm Lit (Term Int)) => Lit -> Term Int
```

The 'Expected type' is the method's signature with the instance head substituted in. To typecheck a method body whose type is not 'general enough' would need:

1. seeing the method's constraint as part of checking the method's body;
2. seeing that the class for that constraint has a FunDep, and that it improves the return type from the argument type;
3. finding the applicable instance of `IsTerm` for the instance of `Eval` (and instances for any constraints on that instance, recursively);
4. improving `c` to `Term int` via the FunDep.

Step 3. in particular is too much to expect: the applicable instance(s) might be declared in a separate module, which is not in scope; in general (unlike this example) it might need an instance for a type scheme/the available instances might be more specific or more general/can't be picked until types are more refined.

But I do have an outstanding question:

- If the type of the method's body is more specific than inferred by substituting in the instance head, what goes wrong?
- The inferred type in the Hugs message is more specific, but also carries the constraints, so they must be discharged for the program to be accepted.
- If the caller of `eval` is expecting a more general type, the more specific result can substitute in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting another answer because it's quite a surprise/a rare beast: code that compiles under Hugs and works; but doesn't compile under GHC (8.6.4). That is unless someone here can see I've gone wrong and can fix it up.

Consider first the **Addit:** example from the 2011 paper. This achieves it in Hugs only (WinHugs 'latest' release Sep 2006)

```
class F a b | a -> b
instance F Int Bool

class D a where { op :: (F a b) => a -> b } 
instance (TypeCast Bool b') => D Int where { op _ = typeCast True }
```

That code is same as in the paper except for the `instance D Int`. I've added a `TypeCast` constraint (and call to its method), which looks weird because type variable `b'` isn't used anywhere.

I've tried various ways round to get that to compile in GHC:

- The `TypeCast` is approximately equal to GHC's `~` constraint, which is not a feature in Hugs; but changing it to `~` won't get GHC to accept the code.
- I've tried various type annotations, including with `ScopedTypeVariables`. Nada.

See [Trac #16430](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/16430#note_189393) for more details, including the definition for `TypeCast` -- which is entirely standard.

Then the code for the original q here goes like this (Hugs only)

```
class    Eval a   where
         eval :: (IsTerm a c) => a -> c 

instance (TypeCast (Term Int) c') => Eval Lit  where
         eval (Lit i) = typeCast (ToTerm i)       -- rejected without typeCast

instance (Eval a, IsTerm a (Term Int), TypeCast (Term Int) c')
         => Eval (Inc a)  where
         eval (Inc i) = typeCast (ToTerm $ 1 + fromTerm (eval i))
instance (Eval a, IsTerm a (Term Int), TypeCast (Term Bool) c') 
         => Eval (IsZ a)  where
         eval (IsZ i) = typeCast (ToTerm $ 0 == fromTerm (eval i))
```

`eval aTerm` (see the q above) now returns `(ToTerm False)`; `eval illtypedTerm` gives a rejection message, as expected.

All of those instances feature that `TypeCast` to a dangling type variable (if "feature" is the right word). It's debatable whether I've achieved any saving of duplicated code as against making `Eval` a class with two parameters that just repeats from `IsTerm`.