# Printing Church Booleans

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, church-encoding

The following code is meant to print Church encoding of booleans as Haskell's `Bool`:

```
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Show (t -> t -> t) where
  show b = show $ b True False
```

Which leads to this error:

```
<interactive>:4:21: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘t’ with actual type ‘Bool’
  ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration at <interactive>:3:10-27
• In the first argument of ‘b’, namely ‘True’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘b True False’
  In the expression: show $ b True False
• Relevant bindings include
    b :: t -> t -> t (bound at <interactive>:4:8)
    show :: (t -> t -> t) -> String (bound at <interactive>:4:3)
```

How to make it work?

Comment: How does it "not work"? Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55077731/edit) to include the exact error messages you get or the exact differences in the behaviour you get and the behaviour you expect.

Comment: You're defining an instance for **any** `t -> t -> t`, but you're specifically using `Bool`s in the definition of `show`, which prevents it being a valid definition for arbitrary `t`.

Comment: You need a `newtype ChBool = ChBool (forall x. x -> x -> x)` if you want instances

Comment: yes, if you do as @Iceland_jack says (you need to use the `Rank2Types` or `RankNTypes` extension) then it works. (You also have to change `show b =` to `show (ChBool b =`

Comment: [Although I have my own question about this, it doesn't work to just put `instance Show (forall t. t -> t -> t) where` even with `Rank2Types` enabled, I get an error about an "illegal polymorphic type" which I don't really understand, particularly as using a `newtype` wrapper for the type seems to be absolutely fine.]

Comment: Would be much easier if you didn't insist on implementing `Show` and instead just had something like `showBoolean :: (forall t. t -> t -> t) -> String; showBoolean b = b "True" "False"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `show :: (t -> t -> t) -> String` should work for **any** function working on **any** type `t`. You are assuming that `t` is Boolean which is illegal, because (according to GHC) "`t` is a rigid type variable" and cannot be unified with specialized type.

---

One possible solution would be to specialize your instance by `Bool` (`FlexibleInstances` are necessary)

```
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Show (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) where
  show b = show $ b True False
```

But this will reduce generality of your Church's boolean.

It is impossible to define flexible solution that would work on any type, because you will need to have two representatives of that type that would describe *true* and *false* cases, and there are types such like `Void` which have no (defined) values.

---

An idea that comes to my mind and is quite universal is to add few more class constraints to `t`:

```
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Data.Boolean

instance (Show t, Boolean t) => Show (t -> t -> t) where
  show b = show $ b true false
```

The `Boolean` class collects types that can be understood as logic values in some terms. For example for `Bool`:

```
instance Boolean Bool where
  true = True
  false = False
  notB = not
  (||*) = (||)
  (&&*) = (&&)
```

And now we can ensure that

- `t` is a thing that you can actually `show`
- There are at least two valid and different values of type `t` that appear as `true` and `false`

Which are the required circumstances to actually be able to `show` a function of such signature in this way.

**IMPORTANT**

Following example won't work:

```
show (true :: (Show t, Boolean t) => t -> t -> t)
```

The problem is that typechecker won't guess which `t` are you going to have here. This solution provides valid and working instance, but only for fully instantiated types. If you get ambiguity error, you will need to specify what is `t`:

```
show (true :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool)
>>> "True"

show (true :: Int -> Int -> Int)  -- assuming Boolean instance
>>> "1"
```

---

**EDIT**:

Yet another idea was mentioned in the comments. The solution would be to wrap your Church boolean with `Rank2Type`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

newtype ChBool = ChBool (forall t. t -> t -> t)
```

Which will let `t` be any type independent of the context. Then you may define casual instance like this:

```
instance Show ChBool where
  show (ChBool f) = show $ f True False
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work with the class Boolean (from Data.Boolean) instead of BiExample?

Comment: I was just not aware of this class. I will update my answer

Comment: Your solution with the Boolean class does not work. Try the following to see the error message:

`myTrue :: t -> t -> t
myTrue = \t _ -> t 
main = print $ myTrue`

Comment: First of all, you missed class constraints for `myTrue`: `myTrue :: (Show t, Boolean t) => t -> t -> t`. Second, this won't work for general type obviously because neither `Boolean` nor `Show` class provide sufficient defaults. The instance however is completely valid, and will work for any instantiated type (for example for `myTrue :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`)